# Controller returning application/json instead of view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have a very weird problem. I could access the page and everything was fine until i added a few new routes in my **web.php** routing file. Problem is with 5th route(named **post.create**). The ** are just to highlight the line/route i am talking about:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function()
{
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');

Route::get('post/all','PostsController@index')->name("post.all");

Route::get('post/{id?}','PostsController@show')->name('post.fetch');

**Route::get('post/create','PostsController@create')->name('post.create');**

Route::post('post/store', 'PostsController@store')->name('post.store');

Route::put('post/{id?}','PostsController@update')->name('post.update');

Route::delete('post/delete/{id}','PostsController@destroy')->name('post.delete');

Route::get('category/create','CategoriesController@create')->name('category.create');

Route::post('category/store','CategoriesController@store')->name('category.store');

Route::get('category/all','CategoriesController@index')->name('category.all');

Route::get('category/{id?}','CategoriesController@show')->name('category.fetch');

Route::delete('category/delete/{id}','CategoriesController@destroy')->name('category.delete');

Route::put('category/{id}','CategoriesController@update')->name('category.update');
});
```

When i am accessing this route i get a blank page with a pair of curly braces only, nothing else. There is a message on the browser console that says - **Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json**.

But if i change the route to

```
Route::get('posts/create','PostsController@create')->name('post.create');
```

,which is just add an additional **s**, i get the full view of the page.

I cannot seem to figure out why the earlier route is sending back application/json(seems an empty object). I made no change to the controller function. Here is the code for the PostsController@create function:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('admin.posts.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

I have tried to return a different view or a simple string from this function for this route. Nothing seems to work.

What am i doing wrong, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will serve the first route matched in the order you define them. Since you have `post.fetch` first it is serving that route with 'create' as the `id` parameter.

In your routes file place `post.create` before `post.fetch` so you have:

```
Route::get('post/create','PostsController@create')->name('post.create');

Route::get('post/{id?}','PostsController@show')->name('post.fetch');

Route::post('post/store', 'PostsController@store')->name('post.store');

Route::put('post/{id?}','PostsController@update')->name('post.update');
```

Comment: @Eric_Tucker: That worked. Thanks a lot for the explanation. Learned a new thing by running into a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You should name Blade file as:

```
resources/views/admin/posts/create.blade.php
```

> Blade view files use the `.blade.php` file extension and are typically stored in the `resources/views` directory

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#introduction

**Update**

In comments I've recommended you to move the route before the `'post/{id?}'`.

Comment: the blade file is already named create.blade.php. As i said the same page is visible if i change the route url in definition, even by 1 character. And yes, this file is stored under resources/views/admin/posts/ directory!

Comment: Try to put this route before the `'post/{id?}'` one

Comment: Hey Alex. Thanks, that was the issue really.

Comment: Yes i should have done that. Upvoted now. Although i upvoted your comment already. Actually what happened is by the time i check back for answer i saw both of your answers but was not able to figure out who answered first. Since the other had explanations i accepted that. Thanks for helping out!